# How to start timer on specific date when user picks a date from DatePicker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, datepicker

```
private void DatePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) <--???
{
    if (DatePicker.ValueChanged) <--???
}
```

I'm not sure what code to write at all!

Comment: What are the odds that your program is still running by the due date?

Comment: it just starts the timer on the specific date that you choose. currently it doesn't do anything, i am settung up the gui

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = DatePicker.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
Thread.Sleep(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Yes, remember that will hold the thread for a while. So, make sure to execute it on a seperate thread.